# How to iterate the List inside the pipe in RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8, rxjs6, flatmap

I have a variable which is a list 
`this.formListModel = [studentData1,studentData2,studentData3]`

Now i have to iterate each Student data in above list and need to pass in a method and that method will send these data to backend via API 
So here is the small code

```
 1. this.odataNotificationService.cancelNotification(this.model)
 2.            .pipe(
 3.                tap(() => {
 4.                    someFunctionality..
 5.                    someFunctionality..
 6.                }),
 7.                flatMap(() => this.someFunctionWhichReturnsObservable()),
 8.                flatMap(() =>  this.someSecondFunctionWhichReturnsObservable()),
 9.                flatMap(() => this.formListModel.map(()=>{
                                      return this.thirdFunctionWhichReturnsObservable(form.identifier)
                                   }))
```

Now I have a problem in line 9 and 10 
Here i have a list which is stored in a variable `this.formListModel` where i need to iterate data nd need to send in
the Next function `this.thirdFunctionWhichReturnsObservable(form)`

I have used a map inside flatMap which will never work. 
So I am looking for a solution where I can iterate inside the pipe

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
9.) flatMap(() => combineLatest(...this.formListModel.map(form => this.thirdFunctionWhichReturnsObservable(form.identifier))),
```

You may have to switch `flatMap` to a `switchMap`, I am not sure about this one. You can also use `forkJoin` instead of `combineLatest`. It is for you to experiment. If you need to send the requests in series, I am not sure in how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This solution emits an observable for each element inside `this.formListModel` using the `from` creational operator. Inside `mergeMap` the observable is subscribed to, and the result observable of `this.thirdFunctionWhichReturnsObservable` is returned.
When the outer stream `from(this.formListModel)` completes the `toArray()` operator bundels all results from `this.thirdFunctionWhichReturnsObservable` and emits an array.

You might have to adjust this solution to your needs. I hope it helps.
Replace line 9 with:

```
    switchMap(() => from(this.formListModel)),
    concatMap(identifier => this.thirdFunctionWhichReturnsObservable(form[identifier])),
    toArray()
```

I used `mergeMap` assuming that the order, the results of `this.thirdFunctionWhichReturnsObservable` are returned in matters. If it doesn't, then use mergeMap.

You can read about rxjs flattening operators here:

- [Understanding Marble Diagrams for Reactive Streams](https://medium.com/@jshvarts/read-marble-diagrams-like-a-pro-3d72934d3ef5)
- [Interactive diagrams of Rx Observables](https://rxmarbles.com/#concatMap)